# OAuth 2.0 implementation roadblock

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi

We have a Oracle Sales Cloud to DocuSign java based integration, which was implemented 3 years ago. As DocuSign has mandated OAuth 2.0, we need to make changes to our existing code.

But first we will need the ‘integration key’ and ‘secret key’ for the existing DocuSign integration user. Though we have the username and password, we are still not able to login because DocuSign is sending verification email to the integration user, and we don’t have access to that email. None of the people who implemented this java integration is working anymore in our company.

So this is a road block for us!

Your suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Client ID (same as the integration key) owns the private/public key pair, not the user being impersonated.

The user who is being impersonated needs to approve (consent to) the impersonation. If you don't have access to the email inbox you can either:

1. Get access (or use a different to email)
2. Use administrative consent to grant consent. Administrative consent is granted by the DocuSign account admin, not by the individual. See my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent)